# Is getaddrinfo_a thread safe?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, posix

I want to use getaddrinfo_a function. Is this method thread safe?
In the man page example given uses a global list for resolving the hostnames.
If I manipulate that list in user space then is it safe?
Pseudo-code as follows:

```
static struct gaicb **reqs =NULL; // global list of hostname to resolve.

addToList() {
   ret =
      getaddrinfo_a(
         GAI_NOWAIT,
         &reqs[nreqs_base], 
         nreqs - nreqs_base,
         NULL ); // enque hostname queue.
}

//another thread  method
dequeu_list( int i ) {
   struct gaicb * result = reqs[i] ;
   reqs[i] = NULL;
}
```

Comment: To always be sure that your function is thread safe, you can make a mutex to lock when you are about to call it and to unlock when you are done.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, see in the [source code](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/resolv/getaddrinfo_a.c#L60):

```
...
int
getaddrinfo_a (int mode, struct gaicb *list[], int ent, struct sigevent *sig)
{
...
  no acess to list
...
  /* Request the mutex.  */
  pthread_mutex_lock (&__gai_requests_mutex);

  /* Now we can enqueue all requests.  Since we already acquired the
     mutex the enqueue function need not do this.  */
  for (cnt = 0; cnt < ent; ++cnt)
    if (list[cnt] != NULL)
      {
...
```

It acquires a mutex before accessing `list`.

Anyway it's similar to `getaddrinfo` which is [required](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/freeaddrinfo.html) to be thread-safe:

> The `freeaddrinfo()` and `getaddrinfo()` functions shall be thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks for the answering the question. But for en-queue mutex is acquired in another thread/kernel thread context. I am deleting or manipulating same list in user/process context will that not be an issue?

Comment: got the answer. i have to protect mutex for my list.

Comment: @user50891 This code is running in user mode not in kernel, it's part from glibc.

Comment: if running in async mode then it creates new thread right. That thread has pointer to the global list "reqs".